# How to Make this iFrame Scroll

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, e-commerce

I am embedding an iframe to this clients site. We want to integrate a square store environment and allow them to scroll past the navbar at the top so they have more room to shop. I've done it before but it's slipped my mind on how to replicate. I'd love some help figuring out how to scroll the whole page as one single page to make it feel more fluid. Currently it only scrolls the iframe.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- 
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // WATERFALL TEMPLATE v1.0.1
  // Theme Ported from Pineapple 1.1.0 - www.pa-lib.com
  // Created on the 4.0 Bootstrap framework - www.getbootstrap.com
  // (c) 2017, Justin Hammond Web Design - www.justinpaulhammond.com/web
  // Code licensed under Creative Commons by 3.0. - www.creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/
  //
  // DO NOT REMOVE THIS HEADER, PERMISSION FOR PUBLIC USE GRANTED
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  -->
  <title>Sego Lily Soap</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/pics/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pa-lib.com/pineapple/1.1.0/css/pineapple.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/waterfall.theme.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <style>

  </style>

</head>
<body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="66">


<!-- NAV -->
  <div style="background-color: #fbb18b;">
  <img src="assets/pics/logo.png" class="pa-banner-logo" style="width: 50vmin;padding-top: 30px;">
  <p style="color:#fff;text-align: center;">Yesterday's Traditions, Today's Luxurious</p>
  <hr>


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-toggleable-sm" style="margin-top: -16px;">
<br><!-- FIXES MOBILE SPACING, NEEDED -->
  <!--<div class="container">-->
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" aria-controls="myNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="position: absolute;top: 50%;transform: translateY(-50%);">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <!--
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage"><h1 class="navbar-brand">WATERFALL THEME</h1><img src="assets/pics/logo.png" class="logo" alt="Logo" ></a> 
    -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="products.php">Products</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="frequently-asked-questions.php">FAQ</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="benefits-of-tallow-soap.php">Benefits of Tallow Soap</a></li>
        <!--<li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="myNavbar" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Product Info</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="myNavbar">
              <a class="nav-link" href="frequently-asked-questions.php">Frequently Asked Questions</a>
              <a class="nav-link" href="benefits-of-tallow-soap.php">Benefits of Tallow Soap</a>
            </div>
        </li>-->
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="about.php">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="http://segolilyreflections.blogspot.com">Blog</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <!--</div>-->
</nav>
</div>




<!-- known glitch, once a product is selected the scale goes back to 1, look into -->
<iframe src="https://squareup.com/store/sego-lily-soap-2" style="height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;padding-top:322px;border: none;"></iframe>



<!-- SCRIPTS INCLUDED BECAUSE IFRAME BREAKS FOOTER-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://pa-lib.com/pineapple/1.1.0/js/pineapple.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/12e4399d79.js"></script>
<script>
function pageScrollFix() {
    window.scrollBy(0,1);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to the inline style:

```
overflow-y: auto;
```

Another option - if you are NOT using HTML5 could be:

```
scrolling="yes"
```

Note: Depending on your needs you may want to change the overflow-y to just overflow if you need both horizontal and vertical scrollbars or overflow-x if you need horizontal only.

--- New Options ---

You could try using the following webkit css (assumes `thisframe` is the iframe class):

```
.thisframe::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    /* remove scrollbar */
    display: none;
}
```

Another option would be to wrap the iframe in a div that is about 15px narrower than the iframe, which would essentially hide the scrollbar.

```
.iframe-wrapper { overflow:hidden; width:800px; }
.iframe-window { overflow:scroll; width:815px; }

<div class="iframe-wrapper">
    <iframe class="iframe-window" src="https://www.yoursite.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

And yet another option would be to set the width of the iframe scrollbar to 0px, though probably not the most "elegant" solution.

If all else fails, you could use [jScrollPane](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html) which allows you to replace the browser scrollbars on any element with a custom scrollbar:
and since you can style them with CSS you could make any scrollbar disappear (with something like: `.jScrollPaneTrack { display: none; }`) 
This is assuming of course that you cannot get the webkit CSS to work and/or none of the other options accomplishes the task given whatever browser support requirements you have.

Comment: Although that works for the iframe (it already scrolled) I need the navbar to scroll up out of the view as well as if it was all one page. Didn't quite fix the issue.

Comment: I added some other options above to hide the scrollbar, I don't think without getting ridiculously crazy with elements wrapped with frames wrapped with elements that you can accomplish getting the scrollbar itself to "scroll up out of the view as well"... if I understand your question correctly. Hopefully one of the other solutions I offered gets you were you are trying to go.

Comment: Another thought... If the iframe-wrapper solution gives you what you are after, you may want to add a some margin to the iframe-window content just to make sure that everything in the iframe is visible in all browsers, I think some browsers (maybe it's just mobile) may reduce the scrollbar width to 8px.

Comment: So I don't think you understand exactly what I'm asking which probably isn't your fault. If you loaded this code onto your localhost yourself you'd be able to see what I'm getting at. The navbar/banner is fixed onto the top of the page and won't scroll up. Only the iFrame scrolls so I essentially have only half the page to scroll with as the other half never moves. I need the fixed banner/nav to scroll up off the screen as I scroll the iframe as if it was all one page. Does that help?